# Trigger Notification from Apple Watch

Tags: uilocalnotification, apple-watch

I'm trying to schedule a local notification to fire after a few minutes once a button is pressed on the Apple Watch (I'm testing on the actual device). This is how I'm attempting it:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    [WKInterfaceController openParentApplication: nil  reply: nil {
}
```

And in AppDelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply {

}
```

Problem is, I don't know where to put the code for the notification. I'm pretty sure I have to call openParentApplication to schedule it, but don't know how. I've been reading all over the internet but haven't found anything helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you're almost there :

first Call like this :

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
  NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]
 [dictionary setObject:@"notification" forKey:@"action"];

    [MainInterfaceController openParentApplication:dictionary reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
//handle the reply if you want to... 
}
}
```

Then in your AppDelegate :

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply
        {
  if([[userInfo objectForKey:@"action"] isEqualToString:@"notification"] ){

        //fire the notification 
         UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3];
            localNotification.alertBody = @"Your alert message";
            localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

// you can use Reply(Dictinary); for responding to watchKit extention OK or KO...
        }
```

Dont forget to ask for permission to notification in your appDelegate :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
    UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];

    return YES;
}
```